# REST API $expand field, where type is Sparqube.LookupColumn

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have a field in the OData format in Sharepoint list (like this *_x0420__x0430__x0431__x043e__x040*). It has Sparqube.LookupColumn type. I have tried to expand this field to get Title (with adding OData_ before field):

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List')/items?$select=OData__x0417__x0430__x0434__x0430__x04/Title&$expand=OData__x0417__x0430__x0434__x0430__x04/Title
```

But I get the response that the field does not exist.

Can I expand this field by another way? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Sparqube LookupColumn support:

> Unfortunately, $expand, $filter and similar APIs are not supported for custom fields, however you can obtain values using different API FieldValuesAsText.
>   Request URL should be 
>   */_api/lists/getbytitle('List')/items(itemId)/FieldValuesAsText*

This will return list item data with fields as text so all lookups will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For `$expand`, you only include the lookup field name, not the sub-fields. Try changing your URL to:

`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List')/items?$select=OData__x0417__x0430__x0434__x0430__x04/Title&$expand=OData__x0417__x0430__x0434__x0430__x04`